# How to extract column value and not the formula inside the cell for script editor in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm extracting a column daily that deletes itself after the day has ended. However when I extract this column, it extracts the formula and not the cell value which are texts. I just want to extract text only

At the moment I have extracted the range and what's inside the cell. The formula in the cell copies a cell if a box is ticked in the consecutive cell. The code only extracts the formula.

```
var uploadSheet_undone=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Day summary for week')
  var undone_tasks_range =sheet_daily.getRange('U3:U119');

  var lastRow_undone=uploadSheet_undone.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn_undone=uploadSheet_undone.getLastColumn();
  var undone_tasks_values= undone_tasks_range.getValues();

  var list_undone=uploadSheet_undone.getRange(1,lastColumn_undone+1);
  undone_tasks_range.copyTo(list_undone);
```

I expected the cell text to be extracted and not the formula. What shows in the column is #REF for reference of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out how to do it.

With the line:

```
undone_tasks_range.copyTo(list_undone)
```

I should put:

```
undone_tasks_range.copyTo(list_undone,{contentsOnly:true})
```